# Cannot download armhf architecture debs

Tags: apt

I am trying to understand why I cannot download any debs where the architecture is 'armhf' from my repository even though the deb is available? I do not have problems downloading any debs where the architecture is 'all'.

```
// target package version does exist:

# apt list -a my-package
Listing... Done
my-package/stretch 1.0.4 armhf
my-package/stretch 1.0.3 armhf
my-package/stretch 1.0.2 armhf
my-package/stretch 1.0.1 armhf
my-package/stretch 1.0.0 armhf



// I just cannot download it:

apt download my-package=1.0.1 --print-uris
E: Version '1.0.1' for 'my-package' was not found



// I have even enabled architecture

cat sources.list
deb [arch=armhf trusted=yes] https://apt.my-domain.com/ stretch main
```

Answer (score 0):

My system's architecture is amd64, and I'm trying to download a package with another architecture. By default, apt will not allow for this unless you specify the architecture: `apt download my-package:armhf=1.0.1 --print-uris`.